# How do I hide leaf hints on my Ancestry family tree?

Tags: ancestry.com, hints

**Is there a way to hide the green leaf hints on my Ancestry family tree?**

I want to take screenshots of my Ancestry family tree so I can frame them for my sister's upcoming wedding. The only problem is finding a way to hide the green hint icons.

Last year I was able to do this by creating an Adblock Plus filter for the hint icons `.iconLeafImageSize1.iconLeafImage.icon`. However, for some reason that doesn't seem to be working this time around.

[image: Ancestry hints]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The selector you're using (.iconLeafImageSize1.iconLeafImage.icon) is definitely still the one they use on ancestry's site. I'm not sure why the filter that was working previously in AdblockPro is no longer working (I tried adding it myself but was also unable to get it to work).

If your aim is just to take screenshots, you can still achieve this without using the AdblockPro filter - you can simply add a new rule in your local stylesheet to hide this element.

The rule you want to apply is:

```
.icon.iconLeafImage.iconLeafImageSize1 {
    display: none;
}
```

In Chrome, this can be done with the built-in developer tools:

1. Open the **Developer Tools** sidebar with <kbd>F12</kbd>
2. Select the **Styles** tab
3. Click the **New Style Rule** button

   [image: Chrome - New Style Rule button]
4. Replace the default `body` element with **`.icon.iconLeafImage.iconLeafImageSize1`**

   [image: Chrome - Adding leaf element]
5. Set the element properties to **`display: none;`**

   [image: Chrome - Setting element properties]

Similar tools exist in all other modern browsers. If you have trouble, please post which browser you're using and I'll try to help you.

Having added this rule, all the hint icons will magically disappear, but only until you next reload the page!  So you may need to add it again to take different screenshots. The image below shows the developer toolbar open with the rule added in manually on the right.

[image: Ancestry tree without leaf icons]

Comment: As an aside, you can use the "Stylish" extension in Chrome to set up a profile for Ancestry so it always applies your extra styles. I did that a few versions ago to hide the images (which I never use) so I could squeeze more of the tree into view with the same font size.

Answer (score 1):

Unless something has changed since, I suspect there is no simple way to do this, because on 30 Mar 2014 [Hannah L, a Community Moderator at Ancestry support forum, said](https://support.ancestry.com/s/question/0D51500001jn68oCAA/hints-how-to-hide):

> We do have the feature to turn the hints off, meaning to not produce
>   any more hints, but this feature will not get rid of the hints you
>   already have received. In order to get rid of those hints you would
>   need to ignore each hint individually. You can submit feedback on the
>   current feature or suggest a way to ignore all of the hints you
>   already have through the feedback form.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative if this isn't working now, or just for less 'techy' types who can work the basics of a photo editing program.

Just grab the tree onscreen then copy and paste (aka clone) a 'clean', non-leafy top right box area of one of your ancestors over the leafed ones. Once for males, then a pinkish one for females.

Not so neat for the boxes where you've added photos clearly, but you can do some detailed work to improve that.

Comment: How do you copy paste a family tree? Can you elaborate with screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

Another way if you're quick.

When I refresh the page, there is a moment before the icons appear. Hit whatever buttons you use for "Print Screen" at this point, and you've got the tree without the leaves. Then load into Photoshop or whatever, tidy up and you're good to go. (May need a couple of tries, but it works beautifully for me).